# Сохранить вложения из Email

Tags: java, email, ews

Хочется из входящих писем выбирать вложения типа `doc`, `docx` (возможно еще какие-то файлы документов). Написал метод, но он только лишь создает файлы соответствующих имен и расширений на диске, но не записывает в них содержимое. Помогите, пожалуйста, подкорректировать:

```java
public ObservableList<ReadMail> mailList() throws Exception{
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        for (Item item : findResults.getItems()) {
            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId());
            mailList.add(new ReadMail(message.getSender().getName(), item.getSubject(), 
                        formatter.format(message.getDateTimeReceived())));
            AttachmentCollection attachmentsCollection = message.getAttachments();
        for (int i = 0; i < attachmentsCollection.getCount(); i++) {
                Attachment attachment = attachmentsCollection.getPropertyAtIndex(i);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test\\" + attachment.getName() , true);
                    byte[] buffer = attachment.toString().getBytes();
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }                   
        }
        return mailList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:**

```java
public ObservableList<ReadMail> mailList() throws Exception{

        String[] attachExtensions = {".doc", ".docx"};
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

        for (Item item : findResults.getItems()) {

            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId());
            mailList.add(new ReadMail(message.getSender().getName(), item.getSubject(), formatter.format(message.getDateTimeReceived())));
            AttachmentCollection attachmentsCollection = message.getAttachments();

            for (int i = 0; i < attachmentsCollection.getCount(); i++) {

                FileAttachment fileattaAttachment = (FileAttachment) attachmentsCollection.getPropertyAtIndex(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < attachExtensions.length; j++) {
                    if (fileattaAttachment.getName().contains(attachExtensions[i])) {
                        fileattaAttachment.load("D:\\test\\" + fileattaAttachment.getName());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Type: " + fileattaAttachment.getContentType()); 
            }                   
        }
        return mailList;
    }
```